# How to set a range and not the range value in VBA

Tags: vba, range

I'm trying to figure out how to set a range as a range and not the value of that range.
This is in regards to adding up time sheet hours per week/per person in case that matters.
I literally just got out of vba class last week and I thought this would be a tich simpler.
It certainly seemed that way in class.

Currently:

```
Option Explicit
Dim RegularHours As Single
Dim PWHours As Single
Dim VacationHours As Single
Dim EmployeeName As String
Dim StartLocation As Range

Public Sub BreakdownNumbers()
 Set StartLocation = Range("F2")
  Do
    AddRegularHours
  Loop Until EmployeeName <> StartLocation.Offset(0, -5).Value
 Range("F18").Value = RegularHours
End Sub

Public Sub AddRegularHours()
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim CurrentDate As Date

 If StartLocation = Range("F2") Then                                                        ' If this is the first entry calculated, Then...

    StartDate = Range("B2").Value                                                              ' Set the Default Start Date
    EndDate = Range("C2").Value                                                                ' Set the Default End Date
    CurrentDate = Range("D2").Value                                                          ' Set the Default Current Date
    EmployeeName = Range("A2").Value                                                     ' Set the Default Employee Name

    StartLocation.Select
    Do While CurrentDate >= StartDate And CurrentDate <= EndDate         ' Add up hours while the Current Date falls between the Start and End Dates
        If EndDate = Selection.Offset(1, -3) Then                                      ' If the End Date in the Next Row is the Same as the Current Row, Then...
            RegularHours = RegularHours + Selection.Value                           ' Add Past Hours with Current Hours
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select                                                      ' Select the next row
            StartDate = Selection.Offset(0, -4).Value                                   ' Set the new Start Date
            EndDate = Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value                                     ' Set the new End Date
            CurrentDate = Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value                                ' Set the new Current Date
        Else
            RegularHours = RegularHours + Selection.Value                           ' Add Past Hours with Current Hours
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select                                                      ' Select the next row down
            StartLocation = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)                                     ' Set the new Start Location
            EmployeeName = Selection.Offset(0, -5).Value                            ' Set new Employee Name
            Exit Do                                                                                       ' Exit the Loop
        End If
    Loop
 Else                                                                                                        ' If this is any other selection than the first entry
        StartLocation.Select
        StartDate = Selection.Offset(0, -4).Value                                       ' Set Start Date
        EndDate = Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value                                         ' Set End Date
        CurrentDate = Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value                                   ' Set Current Date
        EmployeeName = Selection.Offset(0, -5).Value                               ' Set Employee Name

    Do While CurrentDate >= StartDate And CurrentDate <= EndDate        ' Add up hours while the Current Date falls between the Start and End Dates
        If EndDate = Selection.Offset(1, -3) Then                                     ' If the End Date in the Next Row is the Same as the Current Row, Then...
            RegularHours = RegularHours + Selection.Value                           ' Add Past Hours with Current Hours
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select                                                       ' Select the next row
            StartDate = Selection.Offset(0, -4).Value                                   ' Set the new Start Date
            EndDate = Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value                                     ' Set the new End Date
            CurrentDate = Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value                               ' Set the new Current Date
        Else
            RegularHours = RegularHours + Selection.Value                          ' Add Past Hours with Current Hours
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select                                                      ' Select the next row
            StartLocation = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)                                    ' Set the new Start Location
            EmployeeName = Selection.Offset(0, -5).Value                            ' Set new Employee Name
            Exit Do                                                                                      ' Exit the Loop
        End If
    Loop
 End If
```

End Sub

Now F2 has the value of 0 in it.
When I Set StartLocation = Range(F2") it does two things:

1.) It returns "0" when I hover over it when "stepping in" (F8)

2.) When I update StartLocation with the address(0,0), it pastes that range address into Range("F2").

It also doesn't really work from that point going forward. But I can't find anything that states why that it isn't working. All the examples I find on the net say Dim the Range, then set it to the desired Cell or cells. If you want the value of it, then use the .Value suffix
;[

Sorry about the comments section of the code. I promise it looks prettier in my sheet!

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

This line is ambiguous:

```
 If StartLocation = Range("F2") Then
```

Are you checking the Values are equal, or trying to see if StartLocation's *location* is F2 ?

If you mean to compare Value's then I always prefer to do that explicitly by Adding `.Value`

If you mean to compare *location*, then

```
 If StartLocation.Address() = Range("F2").Address() Then
```

would work (assuming they're on the same sheet of course).

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply!
I am checking for the location, not the value, which is seems to really want me to have.
Any particular reason why you need to articulate .address() when you have declared it as a range previously and not specified .value?

Comment: I just tried it and when it loops around, it pastes the text "F11" into the cell F2 and throws an error Type Mismatch because it is text, not a number. rats. = /

Comment: What's the purpose of those two main If blocks in your main sub (the `If StartLocation=Range("F2") Then`...) ?  Both appear more or less the same.

Comment: Essentially, The If Start Location = Range("F2") is there

Comment: Grr, Shift + Enter    <_<

The Range(F2) is there to see if this is the first row of information. When that week of hours is added up, i will paste them somewhere else (not determined yet) and loop again to add up more hours.

That is where the saved range comes in, so i can start off fresh at the beginning of a new week.

Comment: It would help a lot to show some sample data -  you can add it to your question.